# (ASP.NET )Store currently selected Asp:Listbox item as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to store the text of the currently selected item of an Asp:Listbox in a variable. The value is always stored a null, or I receive the error
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Listbox declaration below

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbModules" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbModules_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:ListBox>
```

Code for SelectedIndexChanged below
`

```
protected void lbModules_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = lbModules.SelectedItem.Text;        
            int week = 1;
            UpdateTextBox(week, code);
        }
```

`
The listbox is being populated elsewhere with a method looping and adding values with listbox.items.add

I have tried
`listbox.SelectedItem.Text, listbox.SelectedValue.Text, listbox.SelectedItem.Value, listbox.SelectedValue.Value,`

Nothing I try returns the text of the selected value, always throws an exception or returns null.

Comment: you can do null check ... but root cause it not here ... just search for "***whatever is null here*** is null" and prolly you would find similar questions ... also WebForms in 2022 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first up, it does not make much sense to use the selected index change event UNLESS you have a autopostback=true.

So, if the user is to enter some info into text box etc., then the user say hits your submit button, then I not really sure of any value of using the selected index change event. But, with autopost-back it does.

hence, this markup:

```
        <h2>Select Hotels</h2>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Width="190px" Height="160px" >
        </asp:ListBox>

        <h3>Selected value</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT ID,HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                ListBox1.DataSource = rstData;
                ListBox1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
            TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }
```

Note VERY but BEYOND careful that we ONLY load the listbox ONE time. Since for any event trigger on a page, the on-load event fires first, and THEN you code stub for the given button or event. Thus, if you load up the lb, or grid or in fact "any" data, but fail to include the all important if !IsPostBack code stub?

Then you cannot actually build a working web page!!! (so, my last 200+ web pages I have built ALL have and ALWAYS have that real first page load, since as noted, the on-load event triggers always on post-backs. So, if you load up the lb or anything again, it will blow out and overwrite your selections you have made).

So, above results in this:

[image]

However, if user is to enter data, select things, and THEN hit a submit button, then of course you probably would remove the autopostback = true. And place the above code behind the button click, and NOT use the selected index change event.

Even if you add items to the lb with code, the above rules still apply.

So, say this listbox:

```
        <h2>Select Hotels</h2>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Width="190px" Height="160px" >
        </asp:ListBox>

        <h3>Selected value</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

We still need the autopostback, and thus this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            string MyText = "Item # " + i;
            ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(MyText, i.ToString()));
        }
    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
            TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }
```

And now we get/see this:

[image]

So, either you are missing autopostback, or you are re-running your code to fill the lb each time on post-back, and that will as noted blow out any selecting the user makes.